# Value is empty in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, null, call

I am developing an Instagram application. Nevermind, my questions isn't focused on the API.
Its a simple php question. However. Everytime I try to run the the output is that the TOKEN is empty.

```
 $token = 'XxXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX';

$access_token_parameters = array(
    'access_token'       =>      $token,
    'action'             =>      'like'
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_GET,true);

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_GETFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo curl_exec($curl);

}
```

Is there a way to set a value externally the Array? (Between, I tried it with include file.php. which works.) But I would like to call this without using an external php file.

Hope you understand my problem and may help me :)

Comment: Can you test if the var is set by `var_dump($access_token_parameters)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $token = 'XxXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX';

$access_token_parameters = array(
    'access_token'       =>      $token,
    'action'             =>      'like'
);

$curl = curl_init($url."?".http_build_query($access_token_parameters ));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo curl_exec($curl);

}
```